# Select Values with lowest date

Tags: sql-server

i have table Rates

```
Key   Rate      Dt
1      2      201401
1      2      201402
1      3      201403
2      1      201308
2      2      201309 
2      1      201301
```

and i want to select the Key and rate that has the lowest Dt.

so the result should look like :

```
   Key   Rate      Dt
    1      2      201401
    2      1      201308
```

I tried this :

> select Key,Rate,Dt from Rates where Dt = ( select MIN(dt) from Rates
>   group by Key)

but its not selecting the lowest date only for the specific key... Can you help me please?
Thank you

Comment: What's the Dt columns data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) to get the relevant records...

```
;
WITH    cteLowestDate
          AS ( SELECT   [Key]
                       ,Rate
                       ,Dt
                       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Key] ORDER BY Dt) AS 'rownum'
               FROM     Rates
             )
    SELECT  [Key], Rate, Dt
    FROM    cteLowestDate
    WHERE   rownum = 1
```

I have added a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/210e1/1)

Comment: This does not select all the values with lowest date. This selects **one** of the values with the lowest. The whole construction with the CTE and ROW_NUMBER() is not necessary. -1

Comment: @TT., check the fiddle! This version is far more concise than what you've come up with.

Comment: @christiandev It's simply not what the OP asked for. If you wanted all rows for lowest date, you should have used RANK. Anyway, you got the checkmark for what I consider an inferior solution. To each his own I guess.

Comment: @TT., from *and i want to select the Key and rate that has the lowest Dt.*, I see the OP is specifying singular and not plural - are you suggesting the OP want's all Key(s) that match the lowest dt?

Comment: @christiandev The question reads "Select Values with lowest date". That is open to interpretation maybe. But what use would it be to only select one of the values with the lowest date for a key? I can't see any, hence my objection. Then, if key+date were a PK, the CTE with row numbers is overkill. No need to number things, just find the lowest date for keys, and return their associated rates. But the OP thinks it's good enough, then sure, you get the checkmark. I doubt he understands the effects of such a statement since he couldn't come up with a solution himself. Just my 2c.

Comment: @TT., I still think it's a weak argument to downvote, but that's my 2c.  I see *CTEs* being used far more for this type of solution that the one you've provided.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT KEY,
       Rate,
       Dt
FROM   (SELECT KEY,
               Min(dt) dt
        FROM   Rates
        GROUP  BY KEY) A
       JOIN Rates B
         ON A.KEY = B.KEY
            AND A.dt = B.dt
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant this:

```
  SELECT
    yt.key,
    yt.rate,
    yt.dt
  FROM
    (
      SELECT
        key,
        MIN(dt) AS min_dt
      FROM
        rates
      GROUP BY
        key
     ) AS kmd
     INNER JOIN rates AS yt ON
       yt.key=kmd.key AND
       yt.dt=kmd.min_dt
```